# Subtract values in a group

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables with the same structure and I would like to subtract one from the column (quantity) but I am not getting it, it follows as tables.

| idProduct | amount | classification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 18 | AA |

| idProduct | amount | classification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 16 | AA |

```
SELECT p.[idProduct], ((IsNull(p.[amount], 0)) - IsNull(s.[amount], 0)) AS inStock, p.classification FROM table1 AS p
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS s ON p.[idProduct] = s.[idProduct]
    GROUP BY p.[idProduct], p.[classification], p.[amount], s.[amount]
```

| idProduct | amount | classification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | A |
| 1 | -15 | A |
| 1 | 17 | AA |
| 1 | 2 | AA |

Comment: Why are you using GROUP BY when your select list has no aggregates? And explain the logic needed to generate your desired output. I do not see how a value like -15 is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema:

```
 create table table1 (idProduct int, amount int, classification varchar(100));
 insert into  table1 values(1,  1,  'A');
 insert into  table1 values(1,  18, 'AA');
 
 create table table2(idProduct int, amount int, classification varchar(100));
 insert into table2 values(1,   1,  'A');
 insert into table2 values(1,   16, 'AA');
```

Query:

```
SELECT p.[idProduct]
     , ((IsNull(p.[amount], 0)) - IsNull(s.[amount], 0)) AS inStock
     , p.classification 
FROM table1 AS p 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS s 
     ON p.[idProduct] = s.[idProduct] and
     p.classification=s.classification
GROUP BY p.[idProduct], p.[classification], p.[amount], s.[amount]
```

Output:

| idProduct | inStock | classification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | A |
| 1 | 2 | AA |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=550870f213006f355471524d48ee4300)*

Comment: Thank you very much, now I saw what was missing

Comment: You are most welcome. Best wishes.